# bootstrap seven colum in a row

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using bootstrap and I need to create a "row" with inside seven div. It's a row containing seven custom ceckbox, one for each day of the week. this is a picture of what I'm trying to do.

[image]

I saw an example showing this is what i wrote now:

```
<div class="container col-md-12">
    <div class="row seven-cols col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label class="checkbox-inline ggsettimana ggsettimanabox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Lunedì
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label class="checkbox-inline ggsettimana ggsettimanabox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Lunedì
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label class="checkbox-inline ggsettimana ggsettimanabox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Lunedì
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label class="checkbox-inline ggsettimana ggsettimanabox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Lunedì
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label class="checkbox-inline ggsettimana ggsettimanabox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Lunedì
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label class="checkbox-inline ggsettimana ggsettimanabox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Lunedì
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label class="checkbox-inline ggsettimana ggsettimanabox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Lunedì
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I set the same size for every div and display all of them in one column?

Comment: I just tried this on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjk2o0s6/  and it's vertical.  Is there CSS you have, and if so, can you past it here too?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i presume you're trying to use the grid system for this. You wont be able to, simply because 7 doesn't go into 12. You could quite easily do the css yourself, giving each div a width of 10% and give the container a margin of 15% on the left and right.

Without much detail i can't help a lot, but you don't have to strictly follow the grid. 7/5 grids don't really work.
I havent used bootstrap in a while, but could you not make each div 1 wide and center it? i use foundation these days, and i know you can with that.

edit: found an example of centered columns: http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns